# RESTful way to handle missing data

Tags: rest

I am developing a RESTful API. One of the URLs allows the caller to request the record for a specific person by id.

What is the conventional value to return of the record for that id does not exist? Should the server send back an empty object or maybe a 404, or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404, or perhaps 410 (Gone) if it was there before (but 404 isn't wrong in this case either).

As always with REST, it's also preferable to send a representation with it (even with a 4xx code) to tell the client that the resource does not exist and tell it what possible actions it can take from there.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I return a 404 error from my RESTful API in these cases, based off of the convention used by [CodeIgniter Rest Server](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/06/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter).

This works out fine for the most part, and is the most "correct" and "pure" solution. However  the 404 error can make it a bit harder to handle those "missing" cases on the client because you may need a separate error handler instead of just doing nothing because you got back an empty object.

I would recommend weighing the pro's and con's of both approaches and implementing the approach that makes the most sense for you.

Comment: How does the client distinguish between a URL path that does not exist and a record that does not exist?

Comment: There is no distinction since neither exists. However, I quite like @Bruno's suggestion of sending a representation with the 404 code - this could be used to make such a distinction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to considering 404, I would consider the possibility of returning some representation of "empty":  Consider a Google search for the word [klinjeraliknoplidocus](http://www.google.com/search?q=klinjeraliknoplidocus).  At the time of this writing, it returns 200 OK with "no matches" and suggestions no how to move forward.  It does not return 404, since the URI `http://www.google.com/search?q=klinjeraliknoplidocus` actually identifies something, namely "All documents known to Google that are related to the term *klinjeraliknoplidocus*".  Pretty soon, this page will show up there.

So:

- if you define your lookup feature as returning zero or more items with this ID then 200 and an empty response makes sense.
- if you define your lookup feature as returning exactly one item, then 404 (or 410) makes sense.

Comment: How about 400 (Bad Request)? That way I can distinguish between a mis-typed URL (400) and an id that does not exist.

Comment: I think Bad Request ought to be reserved for syntactical errors.  A URI identifying garbage isn't syntactically incorrect.  A header which is malformed (e.g. `If-None-Match: abc` missing quotes around the ETag) is malformed; an XML document with syntax errors in a PUT or POST is syntactically incorrect, both could cause 400s.  Doing a GET for /customers?q=12345 or /customer/id/12345 is in itself not syntactically incorrect. 200 or 404 should be used if the customer ID doesn't exist depending on the nature of the definition of the resource.